# Show that a set is a countable base for a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm to show that { $(p,q): p,q \in \Bbb Q, p<q$ } is a countable base for $(\Bbb R,d)$.

Unfortunately I missed class this day and I'm trying to follow along with the book however I don't understand this. If $(\Bbb R,d)$ is the real number line with the Euclidean distance, I don't know how to formally construct a countable base.

Comment: You need to show that that is a base, and that is countable. Do you know what is a base?

Comment: If I understand correctly, a set is a base if every set in the metric space  can be obtained by union of some elements of the set?

Comment: Every "open" set. Yes. So given an open set $U \subset \mathbb R$, you need to write $U$ as a union of $(p, q)$, where $p, q\in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

It's countable because $Q\times Q$ is countable. Let $B=\{(p,q):p,q\in Q \land p<q\}$.Let $ C=\{(r,s):r,s\in R\land r<s\}.$ Then $C$ is a base and $C\supset B$.So to show that $B$ is a base it suffices to show $$x\in t \in C\to \exists s\in B (x\in s\subset t)$$ for every $x\in R$ and $t\in C$. Now if $x\in t\in C$, there exists $d>0$ such that $(x-d,x+d)\subset t$ because $t$ is open.Then there exist $p\in Q\cap (x-d,x)$ and $q\in Q\cap (x,x+d)$. So we have $x\in s\subset t$ where $s=(p,q)\in B$.[...That is,every open set $S$ equals $\cup F$ for some $F\subset C$, and every $f\in F$ equals $\cup G_f$ for some $G_f\subset B$ (because $f\in C$) so $S=\cup_{f\in f}\cup G_f$ presents $S$ as a union of members of $B$.]

Comment: That's very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I want to throw my two cents, since I think that the definition of basis recalled above is a little bit difficult to check, especially for a beginner (that's just my opinion). In order to do that I recall the definition of basis given by **Munkres** in *Topology*:

**Definition.** If $X$ is a set, *basis* for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that

1. For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$;
2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Clearly one can prove that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$, then $\tau$ equals the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

The density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ should therefore allow you to solve your exercise.

Comment: I see, thank you for this. I'll take a look at the Munkres book to supplement my studies. I appreciate your help!